# Time Out quano tentar rodar query no Mysql

Tags: mysql, join

Estou rodando o seguinte código:

```
SELECT e.*, e.CO_ESCOLA, es.CO_ENTIDADE 
FROM enem20162 e
INNER JOIN escolas es ON e.CO_ESCOLA = es.CO_ENTIDADE
#WHERE CO_ENTIDADE = 
ORDER BY e.CO_ESCOLA;
```

Quero retornar os alunos que são ligados a uma escola, porém, quando rodo o código no MySQL ele não consegue concluir a execução. Fica tentando executar e nunca termina. Já mudei os parâmetros para aumentar o tempo de execução mas não deu certo.

Comment: vai no mycfg.ini e aumenta o timeout do mysql e o uso de memoria e edita o php.ini e aumenta o tempo de execution dele.

Comment: Já fiz isso... nas realidade não uso php, estou usando localmente. inclusive já tirei o e.*, e continua só rodando.